# For scanf(), why is negated scanset "%[^\n]" showing correct output for "\n", but not the scanset "%[aeiou]" for "aegis"?

Tags: c++, c, newline, scanf, format-specifiers

In the following program, if I use the line for the negated scanset, it works fine if I enter a multi-word line (ending with ENTER or newline), even though the newline is in the negated list.

But if I use the line for the scanset instead and enter the word "aegis" (or any word with consonants for that matter), then junk characters are output. Analogous to the first case, shouldn't at least "ae" be output if I enter this word? Please explain this behavior of scanset and negated scanset for **scanf()**.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
char str[30];
 printf("Enter the string\n");
 //scanf("%[^\n]",str);
 //scanf("%[aeiou]",str);
 printf("%s",str);
}
```

Comment: I don't know what output you get but it works correctly -https://ideone.com/AhfcSL

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @ameyCU I am using codeblocks. Anyways, will it always work the way it is working in your ideone link? Is that the expected behavior always?

Comment: @Thokchom Yes , it will always give output as expected .

Answer (score 3):

It is because code errantly does not check the return value of `scanf()`

```
printf("Enter the string\n");
scanf("%[^\n]",str);
scanf("%[aeiou]",str);  // check result before using `str`
printf("%s",str);
```

With `scanf("%[^\n]",str);` and input like `"123\n"`, `str` get the values of `"123"` **and `'\n'` remains in `stdin`**.  Then with `scanf("%[aeiou]",str);` and input like `"aegis\n"`, the first line's `'\n'` blocks saving anything as `'\n'` is not a vowel, nothing is saved in `str` and since code did not check the return value of `scanf()`, does not realized that `str` may be invalid.

1) Always check the return value of `scanf()` and family.

```
if (scanf(some_format, var1, var2, ...) != ExpectedConversionCount) {
  Fail();
}
```

2) `scanf("%[^\n]",str);` to read a line fails 3 things: No input limit, fails to read anything if the the line consists of only `'\n'`.  Without check the return value, `EOF` is not detected.

3) Use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` for user input.

Comment: I am afraid my question doesn't mention using both scanf()–one with scanset, other with negated scanset– at the same time. So there is no '\n' of first line blocking anything. Refer to the ideone link provided by the user ameyCU. He has got the question right.

Comment: @Thokchom Better to post critical element so of your question here rather than relying on an off site.

Comment: What I mean is I haven't used both lines of scanf() in my program. I use only one line at a time (commenting out the other). I referred you that link as ameyCU has got the question right. It will be helpful if you can answer based on that premise.

Comment: @Thokchom The post, uncommenting  1 and only 1 of the 2 commented  lines, with a single input of `"aegis"`, then junk characters are output is not possible IMO. So I suspect some element of the facts presented is in error.  Yet the best coarse of action if still the same: check the results of code's input function, before attempting to use `str`.   Try re-creating the problem and please report the return value of `scanf()`.  If you have trouble re-creating, suspect the problem happened with a version of code with both `scanf()` lies commented out - like the one posted.